# How to get base project directory name in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to get project folder but not work. Please kindly help!

Example:

```
 println grailsApplication.getBaseDir()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to get the base directory --

```
File file = grails.util.BuildSettings.BASE_DIR
```

Comment: It's working like a charm! Very thanks for your helpful answer.